# Difference between two XML documents ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

Is it possible to determine the difference (eg. new element, modified element, removed element...) in two XML documents in ruby?

Answer (score 2):

May I quote Aaron Patterson:

> As far as the XML document is concerned, no two nodes are ever equal.
>   Every node in a document is different.  Every node has many attributes
>   to compare:
>
> 1. Is the name the same?
> 2. How about attributes?
> 3. How about the namespace?
> 4. What about number of children?
> 5. Are all the children the same?
> 6. Is it's parent node the same?
> 7. What about it's position relative to sibling nodes?
>
> Think about adding two nodes to the same document.  They can *never*
>   have the same position relative to sibling nodes, therefore two nodes
>   in a document cannot be "equal".
>
> You *can* however compare two different documents.  But you need to
>   answer those 7 questions yourself as you're walking the two trees.
>   Your requirements for sameness may differ from others.
>
> I wouldn't be opposed to implementing a =~ on Node that did this
>   comparison, but was very strict about those questions.
>
> You could do stuff like:
>
> doc1 =~ doc2 # => true
>     doc2 =~ doc3 # => false
>
> As long as it only returned true or false.  How does that sound?
>
> --  Aaron Patterson http://tenderlovemaking.com/

---

Otherwise, [there are lookarounds](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/955902):

load the XML doc into a hash with `Hash#from_xml` and compare the hashes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Problem in this solution is that I need to determine what is the difference between two xml documents

Comment: Yes it works but I'm only able to determine if the two documents are/aren't different. When I try to visualize the difference with Hash.diff it returns large part of XML document though only one attribute in leaf node is changed